# Vue v-for is displaying some key-values in array and is not displaying others

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, mixins, v-for

Went through some other peoples questions and couldn't find a answer to this problem.

*Here is some code*

mixin.js (at the moment I'm only focusing on the addArtist method):

```
    created: function(){
        console.log("the mixin has been created")
    },
    validations: {
        artistName: {
        },
        artistInfo: {
        },
        artistImg: {
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addArtist: function(name, info, img){

            let anArtist = [{
                                theArtistsName  : name,
                                theArtistsInfo  : info,
                                theArtistsImage : img,
                            }];

            return anArtist;
        },
        deleteArtist: function(){

        },
        queryArtist: function(queryString){

        }
    },
    data(){
        return {
            showArtistForm: false,
            artistName: '',
            artistInfo: '',
            artistImg: '',
            artists:[   {
                            theArtistsName  : "Tony",
                            theArtistsInfo  : "Good singer",
                            theArtistsImage : "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/1.jpg"
                        }
                    ],
        }
    }

}
```

and the HelloWorld.vue file

```
  <div class="page">
    
    <h1>Artist Directory</h1><br/>

    <input v-model="nameFilter" placeholder="Filter by artist name"><button v-on:click="displayArtistForm = true">Add artist</button><br/>

    <div v-if="displayArtistForm == true" class="artist-form">
      <input v-model="artistName" placeholder="Enter the artist's name."><br/>
      <input v-model="artistInfo" placeholder="Enter info about the artist."><br/>
      <input v-model="artistImg" placeholder="Enter a URL of the artist"><br/>
      <button v-on:click="artists.push(addArtist(artistName, artistInfo, artistImg))">Add Artist to the list</button>
    </div>

    <div class="artist-list">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="artist in artists" v-bind:key="artist">
          <div class="artist-obj">
              <div class="artist-image-box">
                  <img src = "artist.theArtistsImage" class="artist-image">
              </div>

              <div class="artist-info-box">
                  <h2>{{artist.theArtistsName}}</h2><br/>
                  <p>{{artist.theArtistsInfo}}</p>
              </div>

              <div class="artist-delete-button-box">  
                  <button v-on:click="deleteArtist()">Delete</button>
              </div> 
          </div>  
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import mixin from './mixin';

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  mixins: [mixin],
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      artistName:'',
      artistInfo:'',
      artistImg:'',
      nameFilter: '',
      displayArtistForm: false,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now at the moment when I launch on my localhost the div v-for loop will display a broken image file, Tony, good signer, and a button. However; when I press the add artist button, add some values to the text fields and hit the add artist to list button it acts very odd. It will add an object to the list, and when debugging inside the mixin.js file I can see it returning for example: **theArtistsName: "PETE" theArtistsInfo : "Spaghetti guitar"** etc... But in the for loop it will only output: a broken image, and a button. Why wont it print out Pete and spaghetti like it prints out Tony, good signer??? Anyhelp would be appreciated

~Thanks :D

Comment: you shouldn't use a mixin for data, its not reactive

Comment: also `<img src = "artist.theArtistsImage" ` should be `<img :src="artist.theArtistsImage"`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone OHHH! Thanks the image thing is working now :D !

Comment: also, your pushing an array with a single object, to artists not an object

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Ye I noticed that a few mins later haha Thanks though :D